# Android signed APK loading json data using retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an app that uses retrofit to load data from json file on server. When I run the application on a real device or AVD it loads json to my recyclerview's items and every thing is fine. But when I build an signed APK and then install the app, it doesn't load the json's data like my images urls and ...

```
    # Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile


-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8


# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions


# Retrofit
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.gson.** {public private protected *;}
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.xml.stream.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.appengine.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.*
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**

# Retrofit 2.X
## https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ##

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class io.plaidapp.data.api.dribbble.model.** { *; }

-keep public class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationPresenter { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView { *; }
```

Comment: I assure you the signing has 0 effect on loading JSON files.  It doesn't alter the code at all.  Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You may want to add logs around where your JSON data is being downloaded and parsed. This would tell us if it's an issue with the downloading portion or the conversion from JSON to Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `proguard`, you need to keep your model classes used for Retrofit.

Use `-keepclass` and specify all your model/pojo classes.

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're generating your signed application, ProGuard is executing its minification rules against your code. You mention you are using Retrofit. Retrofit's documentation includes ProGuard rules that need to be included in your application as well:

```
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

Additionally, since Retrofit is built on top of Okio, you may need to include Okio proguard rules as well:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Answer (score -3):

Set minifyEnabled to false in your build.gradle file.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
```